# Error while creating masterflow

Tags: android-studio

Gradle 'masterDetail' project refresh failed

Error:Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0: No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: did you find any solution for this

Comment: you should mark the answer from @cindy accepte.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck "Offline work" in Android Studio, then select Tools → Android → Sync Project with Gradle Files